@react-native-async-storage/async-storage fails to compile on Android after upgrading to RN 0.73.8
I'm upgrading our app to RN 0.73.8 using the RN upgrade helper and when trying to run the Android build the process stops with errors related to Android Room libs missing:
e: file:///Users/[redacted]/work/mobile-app/node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/asyncstorage/next/StorageSupplier.kt:13:22 Unresolved reference: Room
[...]

We're using the latest AsyncStorage version. Any idea of what could I have missed? In our project we already use Room for one of our native modules and there it looks like everything is fine:
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.2"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.1.0'
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2"

